# Can’t enable Roundcube plugin

Tags: roundcube

I have a webmail RC on LAMP stack hosted locally in Ubuntu 16.04 I wanted to hear a sound each time new e-mail arrives. I did everything to enable the plugin, but there’s no sound. What I do is this:
 1) Change the name of plugin’s config file from config.inc.php.dist to just config.inc.php This file resides in plugin’s own directory;

2)  In that file I change false to true;

3) Go to main RC config file in config directory config.inc.php and at the bottom of it add the plugin’s name into the array brackets like so:
    $config[‘plugins’] = array(‘newmail_notifier_sound’);

4) Restart Apache.
    Then I send an e-mail to myself and I receive it OK, but I can’t hear any sounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. First of all, the plugin name wasn't 'newmail_notifier_sound', but just 'newmail_notifier'. Secondly, I use Chromium browser (Chrome in Ubuntu basically). Also I allowed my domain to make sounds in the browser's settings. And the last thing... I put a "V" checkmark in "Check all folders..." in MailBox View settings of RC's settings.